# custom module write messages to Kofax log files

Tags: kofax

When creating export scripts it is possible to log information to the Kofax log files. An example would be

```
documentData.LogError(0, 0, 0, "error log", "Export Script", 0);
```

When creating custom modules, is there an equivalent method? Due to the fact the application is an external program I am not sure if it's possible to write to the Kofax log files.

But maybe some objects during **setup** and **runtime** have some log methods.

The interfaces *IBatchClass* (setup), *IBatch* (runtime) and *IACDataElement* (runtime) don't have any of these methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup**

Use the `LogError` method on the `AdminApplication` class that is exposed by Kofax when the setup OCX loads.

**Runtime**

Custom modules rely on the `Kofax.Capture.SDK.CustomModule` assembly. You can either log errors with the `ILogin` or `Login2` object using the `LogError` method - this one has the same signature as for the export connectors, or you could go the extra mile and implement some real logging using [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Here's an example how to use the login object during runtime:

```cs
static void Run(string[] args)
{
    // start processing here
    // todo encapsulate this to a separate class!

    // login to KC
    var login = new Login();
    login.EnableSecurityBoost = true;
    login.Login();
    login.ApplicationName = "Quipu.KC.CM";
    login.Version = "1.0";
    login.ValidateUser("Quipu.KC.CM.exe", false, "", "");
    // more code comes here
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Currently my application doesn't use `ILogin2`. How would you create an instance on setup and release side =?

Comment: @hrp8sfH4xQ4 added a few more lines that should explain the whole concept. Let me know if this helps.